# VueJS How to emit an event from a child component to its parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I emit an event from a child component to the parent component after store dispatch/getters in `vue` ?

I have this structure

```
<parent-component>
     <child-component />
<parent-component>
```

then in the child-component, I have a computed value which returns data from the store

```
computed: {
    getData(){
       return this.$store.getters['albums/user_albums']
// WHEN THIS DATA IS LOADED EMIT TO PARENT
}
```

then, also in the child-component, in the mounted lifecycle:

```
mounted(){
  this.$store.dispatch("albums/read");
}
```

I want to emit an event from child to parent, to do some extra logic on the parent component.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why would you want to emit anything in the computed property? As for the action in your mounted hook, is the action asynchronous? What does it return?

Comment: should consider doing the emits in a method.

Comment: OK why the down vote??

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it by setting up a watcher for the computed value

so in the child component:

```
watch: {
    getData(data) {
        this.$emit("userAlbums", data);
    }
}
```

maybe this can be useful for someone else.